# regular expression for validating url with sub-domain

Tags: php, regex, url, subdomain

```
preg_match('/^(http:\\/\/)?(.+)\.MYDOMAIN\.com(.*)/', $url, $match)
```

This is my regex to validate a URL that must have a sub-domain, but if someone uses `www`
instead of sub-domain it also gets validated. For example:

- `http://shoes.en.MYDOMAIN.com/` This must pass
- `http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/` This must fail

How can I edit my regex to fail if the sub-domain is `www`?

Comment: Use backticks to format URLs: `http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/`.  That will stop SO from linkifying them, and from dropping the `http://` in comments.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it with a negative lookahead assertion: `(?!www\.)` which being placed after the protocol check, checks if there is not a `www.` following the start or protocol.

```
/^(http:\\\/\/)?(?!www\.)(.+)\.MYDOMAIN\.com(.*)/.test("www.MYDOMAIN.com")
```

Comment: This is getting failed when i use http. The regex is passing 

http://www.sd.MYDOMAIN.com

It must be failed as it has www

Comment: http://www.shoes.trustpass.MYDOMAIN.com/   why is this getting pass??? It works fine if I remove http://.

After submitting stackoverflow  removes http and www from the url. Kindly add http and www at starting of provided URL

Answer (score 0):

try this one: tested a litle, seems to be working

```
preg_match('/^(http:\\/\/)?([^(www)]+)\.MYDOMAIN\.com(.*)/', $url, $match);
```

Comment: Does not do what you are expecting. The `www` is actually treated as character class, so equivalent to `w` and matches any subdomain that does not contain a `w`.

Comment: you are also missing an escaping slash in the protocol

Comment: This is getting failed if my subdomain starts with www. Like wwwshoes

Comment: It even fails if subdomian has www anywhere in it.

Answer (score 0):

How about first validate the domain using your current solution then check for www using a second expression:

```
(\.www\.|http:\/\/www\.|^www\.)
```