# PHP - Validating Domains with wilcards and/or subdomains

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to compose an validation script in PHP that will be used in conjunction with an API my website offers. The idea is that the user will enter in all of the domains their API should work from, preventing competitors from putting the code on their site. I just want to validate that the domain entered is of a valid format

The following domain types should be allowed:

- xyz.domain.xxxx
- *.domain.xxxx
- domain.xxxx

I've searched around and the snippets of code I've found ([1](http://kevinphillips.co.nz/news/validate-domain-name/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118536/regular-expression-for-validating-url-with-sub-domain), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877687/regular-expression-required-for-valid-domain-name-check-in-php)) tend to reduce all domains to their simplest form, `domain.com` and don't seem to take wildcards or subdomains into account - or seem to operate a bit differently than what I am looking for.

I am hoping, one day, to master Reg Expressions.

Thanks in advance!

***UPDATE: SOLUTION***

I ended up using the RegEx that rejects TLD's - and if the `preg_match` fails, I then run a DNS check on the domain as a safety net that will validate TLD's. This prevents people from entering garbage like `MyNameIsFred`

```
$domain = str_replace('http://', '', strtolower($_REQUEST['domain']));

//Not checking TLDs. Instead if the domain fails, we will check DNS records to see if it is a TLD or somehow otherwise exists.
/* $reg = '/^(?!.{254,})(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?!.*\*\*)([a-z0-9*](?>[a-z0-9-*]*[a-z0-9*])?)(?>\.(?1)){0,126}$/iD'; //TLD domains OK */

$reg = '/^(?!.{254,})(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?!.*\*\*)[a-z0-9*](?>[a-z0-9-*]*[a-z0-9*])?(?>\.[a-z0-9*](?>[a-z0-9-*]*[a-z0-9*])?){1,126}$/iD'; //No TLD
if (preg_match($reg, $domain)!=1) {
    if (!checkdnsrr($domain.'.', 'A') && !checkdnsrr($domain.'.', 'AAAA'))
        //ERROR
}    
//SUCCESS
```

Comment: It's not quite what you're looking for, so not an answer to this question, but it's worth knowing about: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: You're correct - won't really help, but good to know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should validate domains (with wildcards)

```
'/^(?!.{254,})(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?!.*\*\*)([a-z0-9*](?>[a-z0-9-*]*[a-z0-9*])?)(?>\.(?1)){1,126}$/iD'
```

<strike>Will allow TLD-only domains</strike> (removed upon request), or just a `*`.

Won't allow consecutive `*`s.

If the above doesn't work it could be that you're using an older version of PHP (and so an older version of PCRE). The following should fix that issue:

```
'/^(?!.{254,})(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?!.*\*\*)[a-z0-9*](?>[a-z0-9-*]*[a-z0-9*])?(?>\.[a-z0-9*](?>[a-z0-9-*]*[a-z0-9*])?){1,126}$/iD'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting this: `preg_match(): Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (? at offset 80 on line 5` See Example: http://codepad.org/alRevMYZ

Comment: Then it should work. Are you sure you copied it correctly? See: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fib-89a

Comment: See the demo - perhaps I did miss something, but Copy-and-paste is usually spot on. http://www.codepad.org/alRevMYZ

Comment: It works on phpfiddle, true - `stackoverflowcom` seems to be triggering a positive result, though. PS - Codepad could be using an older PHP version, I suppose.

Comment: The expression allows for single-label domains, i.e. `uz` which is a valid domain. It's not the job of regular expressions to check that the domain *actually exists* -- you'd use `checkdnsrr` or something similar (`stackoverflowcom` is a *syntactically valid* domain).

Comment: Obviously its not going to check the existence of a domain, but a single word with no periods should not validate, as per my original post.

Comment: Even though they're valid? OK. Changed.

Comment: To be honest, I've not seen such a domain - is this a standard type of domain?

Comment: `uz` is such a domain (you might need to do `uz.` to hack the browser)

Comment: Well I'll be. There are a finite amount of these, though - right? If so, I could just manually check for them, I suppose. Thanks for the teachings.

Comment: Yes, there are very few. You can run `checkdnsrr($domain, 'A')` or `checkdnsrr($domain, 'AAAA')` (I'm not sure what other record types are relevant) on the TLD list and see which ones return `true`. Although these could change if the people in control of them decide to make them accessible -- `ai` is another that works.

Comment: One more question. Would you advise solely using `checkdnsrr` assuming that I don't care if the domain EXISTS or not?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You use `checkdnsrr` to see if the domain exists. The regexp is just to check syntax first (there's no point using `checkdnsrr` if the domain is incorrectly formed). Although obviously `checkdnsrr` won't work with your wildcards. If you don't care it if exists (or if you want to allow wildcards), you'll just have to use the validation in my answer.

Comment: Perfect Answer. Didn't consider the wildcards. I'm going to use your second regex (no TLD) to validate the domain. If that fails, I will run `checkdnsrr` to see if it exists to validate it.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty straight forward without much testing for the different parts but the general pattern.

```
^([\w*]+\.)?([\w-]+)(\.\w+)$
```

Comment: That only allows `a.b.c`. What about `www.del.icio.us`? Also, allows leading and trailing hyphens, and doesn't limit the lengths of the labels or the domain.

Comment: Like I said, without much testing but straight forward covering the cases the OP showed.